# How can I return an array from a MIPS procedure?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, procedure, calling-convention

What is the standard way of returning an array of addresses or values from a MIPS procedure?

For instance, suppose, I want to read a sentence and want to return the words found in that sentence. Or, suppose, I want to return the positions of the 1st character of each word. And, so on.

Comment: Array is just a pointer to the first element, store it in a register ... and then it can be taken out easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard ways are the same as what you can do in C:

- have the caller pass an output pointer (to an already-allocated array, e.g. on the stack)
- have the function malloc an array and return a pointer.  (Or `mmap` or whatever, but the caller has to know how the memory was allocated, because the caller then becomes responsible for freeing it.)

Or you could do weird stuff like putting the array onto the call stack, and returning with `$sp` modified (so `$sp` points to the start of the array when you return); in assembly language you can make up your own calling conventions if you want.  And maybe return a length or size in `$v0` so the caller can restore `$sp` when they eventually want to return.

This last way is actually good if you don't know the length ahead of time, and you can create the array starting with the tail.  (So it grows downward like the call stack, as you use it like a stack data structure.)

Comment: can u provide either an example or a link to an example?

Comment: @user366312: google can, if you search for `site:stackoverflow.com mips return array`.  e.g. Craig's answer on [After passing the address of an array into a function in MIPs, am I supposed to save the values of the array into a stack?](//stackoverflow.com/q/40078137) is a good example of the first case, where the caller passes a pointer to an array.